# Добавить значение по ключу в переменную типа rowtype

Tags: oracle, plsql

Получаю в `PL/SQl` на сервере `json`, делаю его парсинг. И нужно добавить в переменную типа `rowtype` значения из `json`. 
На сколько я знаю добавить значение в переменную типа `rowtype` можно так

```
пакет_процедур.название_переменной.имя_поля := значение;
```

но как это сделать в цикле что -то типа такого

```
key := json.get_keys().get(1).to_char;
```

-- получаем название поля в таблице, а значит и в переменной rowtype

```
 пакет_процедур.название_переменной[key] := 22; где key - название поля
```

Возможно ли как то это сделать? я новичок в Oracle. Потратил целый день и  не нашёл не чего похожего.

Comment: Простых способов - нет. Сложные - есть, но это примерно как ухо пяткой чесать (неудобно). Много у вас таких полей?

Comment: пару сотен, в каждой из таблиц, поэтому ручками не охота делать. Хочется как то красиво.

Comment: А json парсите на PHP или в PL/SQL?

Comment: в PL/SQL через PL/JSON

Comment: а какие вообще есть варианты? может есть какие то пути решения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Теоретически, внутри цикла можно написать:

```
for i in 1..n loop  -- это цик на PL/SQL
  execute immediate 'begin package_name.variable_name.field' || i || 
                    ' := :value; end;' using json.get_keys().get(i);
end loop;
```

Это так называемый динамический SQL (когда вы генерируете строку с кодом запроса или PL/SQL блока, а потом выполняете), но я бы предложил сто раз подумать, прежде чем так делать (особенно если ожидается большая нагрузка).

Тут вопрос в том, кому вы хотите проще сделать - себе или серверу. Серверу будет проще, если один раз сгенерировать текст в текстовом редакторе. Например, взять список столбцов таблицы из `all_tab_columns` (см. [тут](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-F218205C-7D76-4A83-8691-BFD2AD372B63.htm#REFRN20277)) и автозаменой сгенерировать код.

Comment: Спасибо, немного поправил, перетащил это на сервер приложения, и готово) работает довольно быстро))